# Remove value from Firebase Database issue (Android)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

everyone! I want to delete the value from *Firebase Database* using *RecyclerView*.
However, I cannot find the **key** of a child, which I want to delete.

Firstly, I add data to the database like this:

```
  String key = MainActivity.databaseReference.push().getKey();
  MainActivity.databaseReference.child(key).setValue(myAppModel);
```

In terms of deleting, in my *RecyclerView* adapter i have written *onClickListener* to *ImageView* and delete item from list successfully!
In addition, i tried many ways of how to delete this item from database as well, but the data still untouched.
Here is the code:

```
holder.appDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAppModelList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mAppModelList.size());
               final ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       dataSnapshot.getValue(AppModel.class);
                       MainActivity.databaseReference.child(mAuth.getUid()).child(dataSnapshot.getRef().getKey()).removeValue();
                       System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getRef().getKey()); // it gives me user id...but in my MainActivity it gives the real key
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               };
               MainActivity.databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
            }
        });
```

As i mentioned in code comment, *getRef().getKey()* gives me the Firebase user id, like *mAuth.getUid()*
And in *MainActivity* i receive the real name(key) of child

```
 Query query = databaseReference;
            query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    AppModel appModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(AppModel.class);
                    appModelResult.add(0, appModel);
                    AddAppDialog.setAppModelResult(appModelResult);
                    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getRef().getKey());
                    reloadFragment(fragment);
                }
```

What i should do to delete the data from database?
Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
Initially, when I want to delete item I wrote

```
MainActivity.databaseReference.child(mAuth.getUid()).child(appModel.getAppId()).removeValue();
```

However, as i noticed, you should not write user id

```
MainActivity.databaseReference.child(appModel.getAppId()).removeValue();
```

And here we are!
Hope, it could help everyone